# how to get root folder path in static class or IEnumerable in Asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to get the root folder path of the project in a static class. I have tried so many codes but not getting any solutions. In the controller, I am getting root path using IHostingEnvironment interface. It is possible to get the folder path in a static class?

Comment: What did you try? Please, insert your [code](/help/reprex) to the question! Without it, it's hard to help you...

Comment: IMO, you should avoid using static class in asp.net core. If you insist on, you may consider setting the static class folder path in `Startup.cs`.

Comment: @Edward And what about extension methods? I would use static `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not possible. It lives in `IHostingEnvironment` which must be injected. Static classes cannot be injected into, so you're out of luck. In general, you should avoid statics, and *especially* when using dependency injection. The two approaches are diametrically opposed to each other.

Instead, you can create a class with a singleton lifetime. That buys you the "global" nature of a static, as it will be available to all parts of the application for the life of the application, and you *can* actually inject into that.

```
public class MySingleton
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;

    public MySingleton(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }

    ...
}
```

And then register that as a singleton in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddSingleton<MySingleton>();
```

Note, you're able to inject `IHostingEnvironment` directly here because it too is a singleton. For other things not in singleton scope, such as a `DbContext`, you'll need to use the service-locator pattern, where you'll inject `IServiceProvider` and then do something along the lines of:

```
public void MethodThatUsesContext()
{
    using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
    {
        var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyContext>();
        // do something with context
    }
}
```